# Maven: Debug mode only for one plugin

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

Is there a way to enable Maven debug mode (-X) in order to get debug info which is related only to concrete execution of a maven plugin?
Debug info for all maven steps are too huge to keep and analyze it.

Comment: via `-X` you only turn on debugging logging output...You can redirect into a file and search there for the things you need...

Comment: Yeah, but I'm looking for a way to search in a limited amount of info (debug level only for a particular plugin execution).

Comment: [compiler:compile](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#debuglevel) mentions `debuglevel` _"to be appended to the `-g` command-line switch"._ But this `-g` is not mentioned in [Maven: The Complete Reference](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html) and in the old [Maven 1.x - Command Line Reference](http://maven.apache.org/archives/maven-1.x/reference/command-line.html) it's for something completely different.

Comment: `mvn compile -X -g vars` → `Unable to parse command line options: Unrecognized option: -g`

Comment: @GeriBroser `-g` was an Maven 1 option. So in Maven 2/3 this option does not exist anymore.

Comment: @AntonBalashov May be you can give more details what exactly you are trying to do may be there exist a different way?

Comment: Sometimes I integrate new maven plugins to my projects and not always can write correct configuration for them by first try. So, to figure out what's wrong I have to enable debug info during maven build, but it's too large for example to work with it on Jenkins.
Right now I'm trying to figure out why I can't skip maven-pmd-plugin for 1 of project modules..

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, I'v realized that. So, `compiler:compile`'s page is another case for the mvn mail grp, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: The way i under @AntonBalashov, he wants activate debug output for a specific plugin. None of the answers really addressed his question. I would expect to able to achieve this via plugin configuration in the pom.xml

Answer (score 8):

You can set up logging on the command line using info given here:

- https://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html

Here's an example of setting logging level to `info` for `help` plugin only:

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.plugins.help=info
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do you do this for an *arbitrary* plugin?

Comment: Tried `mvn ... -q -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.plugins.${plugin-name}=${level}`

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi I don't think you can, though it should work for a category: `-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.plugins=info` should work for all `org.apache.maven.plugins`.