# How to pass -X debug option to Maven plugin execution in POM

Tags: maven

I would like to pass the mvn -X debug option to only a particular plugin execution specified in my POM, or to achieve the equivalent by other means. I don't want to pass -X to the entire mvn invocation, as that would result in too much output.

My POM looks something like this (partial):

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>full-project-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>project</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        /<executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

I want only this execution of the assembly plugin to run as if with the -X option. Is there any convenient way to achieve that via the POM?

Comment: It would be easier to define a profile to run this plugin when specified at command line, and then every time you pass the debug option you also use the configured profile

Comment: I can get close to what I am looking for by adapting the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526403/maven-debug-mode-only-for-one-plugin, and passing `-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.plugins.assembly=debug` to the `mvn` command. The main difference is that gives debug output for all executions of the assembly plugin, not just the one I'm interested in.